# Unlock screen effect

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an application for windows phone 7 devices and I would like to make a window with a background image. To enter the application the user must slide the image up. Just like the unlock screen.

Is there a way to make this kind of behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tired thus far.. ? have you done a google search or MSDN search...?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I did search on Google, MSDN and codeproject. But I can't find nothing related to this.

Comment: @WilliamMelani What a great answer ;) It really helped me out

Comment: I am assuming that this app will allow for Touch / look up Gestering and C# also there has to be tons of examples on the net for Windows 7 Phone .. what did you type in the google search..

Comment: you know the behavior you're looking for. While(user is touching, and direction is up, move image up AND move up pincode control) if user stops touching AND pincode control is NOT competely in frame, animate image down to 0,800.. There is no built in control, and it's definitely not trivial, but you need to look at the core of what you are looking for.. specifically touch/gesture support.

Comment: Ok. Touch/gesture support is the key to my problem ;) Thank you DJ KRAZE and William.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a similar question (and answer) on Stack Overflow here: [Mimicking WP7 Unlock Page Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513776/mimicking-wp7-unlock-page-animation)

If nothing else it should give you a starting point. You just need to add your gesture code.

*Note: Found by Googling "wp7 slide unlock control" in about 10 seconds... Google is your friend!*