# Mimicking WP7 Unlock Page Animation error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm try to get the unlock phone effect, using this code
[Mimicking WP7 Unlock Page Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513776/mimicking-wp7-unlock-page-animation?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I really dont know how to make it work. I dont have experience with `Storyboard` and I'm getting an error with `gridTranslate`, as I dont have a deffinition for it. I dont know If i'm putting the code correctly. Can someone help me with this

My xaml code is

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LockScreenGrid" Visibility="{Binding LockScreenGridVisibility}" ManipulationDelta="lock_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="lock_ManipulationCompleted" >
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="GridTranslate" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="LockScreenSlideAnimation">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="-768"  
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="  
   (UIElement.RenderTransform).  
   (CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" 
   Storyboard.TargetName="LockScreenGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Name="CoastGrid" >
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LockScreenGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform)
.(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="coastY"           
        KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0">
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>



    </Grid>
```

and my .cs code is

```
 public SlideTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void lock_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.gridTranslate.TranslateY < 0.0)
        {
            IEasingFunction function;
            this.CoastGrid.Stop();
            this.gridTranslate.TranslateY = e.TotalManipulation.Translation.Y;
            if ((e.IsInertial) && (e.FinalVelocities.LinearVelocity.Y < -1500) ||
            (this.gridTranslate.TranslateY < (base.ActualHeight / -2.0)))
            {

                this.coastY.Value = (-1.0 * this.LockScreenGrid.ActualHeight);
                function = new CircleEase();
                ((CircleEase)function).Ease(1.0);
            }
            else
            {
                this.coastY.Value = 0.0;
                function = new BounceEase();
                ((BounceEase)function).Ease(0);
                ((BounceEase)function).Ease(2);
                ((BounceEase)function).Ease(5.0);
            }
            this.coastY.EasingFunction = function;
            this.CoastGrid.Begin();
        }
    }
    private void lock_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.gridTranslate.TranslateY = (this.gridTranslate.TranslateY +
        e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
        if (this.gridTranslate.TranslateY > 0.0)
        {
            this.gridTranslate.TranslateY = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

It's just copy/paste of the code I got from the source. I dont know If I need some reference, or if I have to define `gridTranslate`

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML has an element named GridTranslate, whereas your code uses gridTranslate - note the different casing.